# How to show localStorage data in header using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

Hello I am working in MEAN Stack And I want show the local-storage value into the

Header of theme.I am using the Metronic theme.

Actually Local Storage data is accessible in view file.everything working fine But

I want to view LOcalStorage data in header that is not showing.

I am using like this.

```
{{adminData.email}}
```

It is not showing email of admin in header.

But when I am using same **{{adminData.email}}** in content file that is

showing mail of admin.I don't know what is the issue.

here is the index.ejs file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style type="text/css">
 .page-spinner-bar {
    display: none;
}</style>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<!--<![endif]-->
<!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
<head>
<title>Ditro Infotech App</title>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<meta content="" name="description"/>
<meta content="" name="author"/>

<!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../assets/global/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../assets/admin/pages/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


<!-- BEGIN DYMANICLY LOADED CSS FILES(all plugin and page related styles must be loaded between GLOBAL and THEME css files ) -->
<link id="ng_load_plugins_before"/>
<!-- END DYMANICLY LOADED CSS FILES -->

<!-- BEGIN THEME STYLES -->
<!-- DOC: To use 'rounded corners' style just load 'components-rounded.css' stylesheet instead of 'components.css' in the below style tag -->
<link href="../../assets/global/css/components.css" id="style_components" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../assets/global/css/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../assets/admin/layout2/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../../assets/admin/layout2/css/themes/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color"/>
<link href="../../assets/admin/layout2/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!-- END THEME STYLES -->

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
<!-- BEGIN JAVASCRIPTS(Load javascripts at bottom, this will reduce page load time) -->

    <!-- BEGIN CORE JQUERY PLUGINS -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/excanvas.min.js"></script> 
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/jquery.cokie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END CORE JQUERY PLUGINS -->

    <!-- BEGIN CORE ANGULARJS PLUGINS -->
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular-sanitize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular-touch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/ocLazyLoad.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.10/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-local-storage/0.2.7/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
    <script nsrc="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>



        <script src="js/module/module.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controller/controller.js"></script>
    <!-- END CORE ANGULARJS PLUGINS -->

    <!-- BEGIN APP LEVEL JQUERY SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="../../assets/global/scripts/metronic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/admin/layout2/scripts/layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/admin/layout2/scripts/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <!-- END APP LEVEL JQUERY SCRIPTS -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* Init Metronic's core jquery plugins and layout scripts */
        $(document).ready(function() {   
            Metronic.init(); // Run metronic theme
            Metronic.setAssetsPath('../../assets/'); // Set the assets folder path          
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- BEGIN PAGE SPINNER -->
    <div ng-spinner-bar class="page-spinner-bar">
        <div class="bounce1"></div>
        <div class="bounce2"></div>
        <div class="bounce3"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- END PAGE SPINNER -->

    <!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
    <div data-ng-include="'js/view/header.html'"  class="page-header navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    </div>
    <!-- END HEADER -->

    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>

    <!-- BEGIN CONTAINER -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-container">
            <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR -->
            <div ng-include="'js/view/sidebar.html'" class="page-sidebar-wrapper">          
            </div>
            <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
            <div class="page-content-wrapper">
                <div class="page-content">
                    <!-- BEGIN STYLE CUSTOMIZER(optional) -->
                    <div ng-view></div>
                    <!-- END STYLE CUSTOMIZER -->
                    <!-- BEGIN ACTUAL CONTENT -->
                    <div ui-view class="fade-in-up">
                    </div> 
                    <!-- END ACTUAL CONTENT -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
        <div data-ng-include="'js/view/footer.html'" class="page-footer">
        </div>
        <!-- END FOOTER -->
    </div>
    <!-- END CONTAINER -->


</body>
<!-- END BODY -->
</html>
```

index.ejs file include header footer and sidebar file.

here is my header file.

```
<!-- BEGIN HEADER INNER -->
<div class="page-header-inner container">
    <!-- BEGIN LOGO -->
    <div class="page-logo">
        <a href="#/dashboard.html">
        <img src="../../../assets/admin/layout2/img/logo-default.png" alt="logo" class="logo-default"/>
        </a>
        <div class="menu-toggler sidebar-toggler">
            <!-- DOC: Remove the above "hide" to enable the sidebar toggler button on header -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END LOGO -->
    <!-- BEGIN RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
    <a href="javascript:;" class="menu-toggler responsive-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    </a>
    <!-- END RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE ACTIONS -->
    <!-- DOC: Remove "hide" class to enable the page header actions -->
    <div class="page-actions">
        <!--<div class="btn-group hide">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle red-pink dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>&nbsp;<span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">New&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    <i class="icon-user"></i> New User </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    <i class="icon-present"></i> New Event <span class="badge badge-success">4</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    <i class="icon-basket"></i> New order </a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    <i class="icon-flag"></i> Pending Orders <span class="badge badge-danger">4</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    <i class="icon-users"></i> Pending Users <span class="badge badge-warning">12</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>-->
        <!--<div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle green-haze dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;<span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">New&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    <i class="icon-docs"></i> New Post </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    <i class="icon-tag"></i> New Comment </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    <i class="icon-share"></i> Share </a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    <i class="icon-flag"></i> Comments <span class="badge badge-success">4</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    <i class="icon-users"></i> Feedbacks <span class="badge badge-danger">2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>-->
    </div>
    <!-- END PAGE ACTIONS -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE TOP -->
    <div class="page-top">
        <!-- BEGIN HEADER SEARCH BOX -->
        <!-- DOC: Apply "search-form-expanded" right after the "search-form" class to have half expanded search box -->
        <!--<form class="search-form search-form-expanded" action="#" method="GET">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." name="query">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn submit"><i class="icon-magnifier"></i></a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>-->
        <!-- END HEADER SEARCH BOX -->
        <!-- BEGIN TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
        <div class="top-menu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">

                <li class="dropdown dropdown-user">
                    <a href="javaScript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-menu-hover data-toggle="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
                    <img alt="" class="img-circle" src="../../../assets/admin/layout2/img/avatar3_small.jpg"/>

                   <span class="username username-hide-on-mobile">
                    {{adminData.name}} q</span>


                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-default">

                        <li>
                            <a href="#/login">
                            <i class="icon-key"></i> Log Out </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- END USER LOGIN DROPDOWN -->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- END TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
    </div>
    <!-- END PAGE TOP -->
</div>
<!-- END HEADER INNER -->
```

Comment: do you have `controller` for **header**?

Comment: no I used header into the main file index.ejs

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ShahzadDitro does your index.ejs file have access to your angular app? Please show code of your index.ejs file, and describe the situation there

Comment: @JunaidSalaat I updated my Question

Answer (score 0):

try to use service/factory. a little not angular way but works fine(ES6)

```
export function metadataService(httpFactory) {
    'ngInject';
    this.setMetaTags = function (title='CONSTART',description= 'CONSTART',foto){
        var bImgUrl = httpFactory.baseImgUrl;
        var photo = foto? bImgUrl+foto :'assets/ico/favicon-32x32.png';
        document.querySelector('meta[itemprop=name]').content = title;
        document.querySelector('meta[itemprop=description]').content = description;
        document.querySelector('meta[itemprop=image]').content = photo;



    };
}
```

and inside your controller/component/directive get your localStorage data and

metadataService(/*localStorage.getItem(someItem)*/)